# Stream and lambdas as parameter

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have multiple functions to filter a map of objects based on criteria.

Functions have the same body, only the boolean pass condition will change.

```
    filterOnFirstCriteria(Criteria criterias, Map<Integer, List<Container>> containerMap, Map<Integer, ClassKey> classKeys) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Container>> entry : containerMap.entrySet()) {
            List<Container> containers = entry.getValue();
            ClassKey classKey = classKeys.get(entry.getKey());
            for (Container container : containers) {
                List<MyObject> found = new ArrayList<>();
                for (MyObject myObject : container.getMyObjects()) {
                    boolean pass = criterias.getListOfFilter().stream().filter(s -> s.equals(container.getReference())).count() > 0;
                    if (pass) {
                        found.add(myObject);
                    }
                }
                container.getMyObjects().removeAll(found);
            }
        }
    }


filterOnOtherCriteria(Criteria criterias, Map<Integer, List<Container>> containerMap, Map<Integer, ClassKey> classKeys) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Container>> entry : containerMap.entrySet()) {
            List<Container> containers = entry.getValue();
            ClassKey classKey = classKeys.get(entry.getKey());
            for (Container container : containers) {
                List<MyObject> found = new ArrayList<>();
                for (MyObject myObject : container.getMyObjects()) {
                    boolean pass = myObject.getListOfObject().stream().filter(obj -> criterias.getLocations().stream().anyMatch(location -> location.equals(obj.getLocation()))).count() > 0;
                    if (pass) {
                        found.add(myObject);
                    }
                }
                container.getMyObjects().removeAll(found);
            }
        }
    }
```

Conditions can be on any objects from upper loops.
I would like to extract the duplicated loop code into a function but I don't know how to pass some kind of callback for the boolean condition.

Thank you.

Comment: Pass an additional Predicate<Context>, where Context would contain all the information necessary for the predicate to decide in it should return true or false (i.e. myObject, container, criterias).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference in both methods are the statements:

```
boolean pass = criterias.getListOfFilter().stream()
    .filter(s -> s.equals(container.getReference()))
    .count() > 0;
```

and

```
boolean pass = myObject.getListOfObject().stream()
    .filter(obj -> criterias.getLocations().stream()
            .anyMatch(location -> location.equals(obj.getLocation())))
    .count() > 0;
```

The first statement does not depend on `myObject` fetched from the inner loop but on `container` fetched from the outer loop. It depends as well on the parameter `criterias` passed to the method.

The second statement depends on `myObject` fetched from the inner loop and on the parameter `criterias` passed to the method.

So if you want to refactor out those statements, which produce the `boolean`, you have to find a unified method supporting both statements like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Guardian {
    boolean pass(MyObject myObject, Container container);
}
```

Now you are ready to extract those two statements and pass them to your new method as lambdas:

```
public static void filterOnFirstCriteria(Criteria criterias, Map<Integer, List<Container>> containerMap, Map<Integer, ClassKey> classKeys) {
    filterOn(criterias, containerMap, classKeys, (myObject, container) ->
        criterias.getListOfFilter().stream()
                                   .filter(s -> s.equals(container.getReference()))
                                   .count() > 0);
}

public static void filterOnOtherCriteria(Criteria criterias, Map<Integer, List<Container>> containerMap, Map<Integer, ClassKey> classKeys) {
    filterOn(criterias, containerMap, classKeys, (myObject, container) ->
        myObject.getListOfObject().stream()
                                  .filter(obj -> criterias.getLocations().stream().anyMatch(location -> location.equals(obj.getLocation())))
                                  .count() > 0);
}

public static void filterOn(Criteria criterias, Map<Integer, List<Container>> containerMap, Map<Integer, ClassKey> classKeys, Guardian guardian) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Container>> entry : containerMap.entrySet()) {
        List<Container> containers = entry.getValue();
        ClassKey classKey = classKeys.get(entry.getKey());
        for (Container container : containers) {
            List<MyObject> found = new ArrayList<>();
            for (MyObject myObject : container.getMyObjects()) {
                if (guardian.pass(myObject, container)) {
                    found.add(myObject);
                }
            }
            container.getMyObjects().removeAll(found);
        }
    }
}
```